# Why doesn't this UnityScript code change scenes in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

In Unity I want to change scenes when the player enters a certain area. The area has box collider and it is set as a trigger, and the script is attached to that area, however when the player enters that area and presses up on their keyboard, nothing happens. I have no syntax errors and it says everything is fine. What could the issue be?

Here is the code:

```
var Level = "";
var Player = "";
function OnTriggerStay(other : Collider) {
    if(other.tag == Player){
        if(Input.GetKeyUp("up")){
            Application.LoadLevel(Level);
        }
    }
}
```

Revised code:

```
var Level = "";
var Player = "";
function OnTriggerStay (consolelog("Hello"))l;
{
if(other.tag == Player){
if(Input.GetKeyDown("up")){
 Application.LoadLevel(Level);
}
}
}
```

Comment: Well, debug this step by step.  Does your function get fired when a key is pressed?

Comment: @Brad I have checked by outputting to console when the key is pressed and it doesn't do anything

Comment: do you intend on checking if the tag is empty?

Comment: @CrudeLogic Then you have narrowed your problem down to a key handler.  Your question doesn't have anything to do with `Application.LoadLevel(Level)`.  I don't know anything about Unity, but take this another step further.  Does `OnTriggerStay` ever run?  If it does, what's in `other.tag`?  What's in `Player`?  Is `Player` really an empty string?

Comment: @CrudeLogic I was referring to your `OnTriggerStay` which seems to get called when a key is pressed.  Test each condition to narrow down the problem further.

Comment: @Brad I dont know if 'OnTriggerStay' runs or not because i have no way of telling seeing as it wont output to the console. And 'other.tag' is basically whatever collides with the area but so everything doesn't activate the if statement that's equal to whatever object is in the variable 'player'.

Comment: @CrudeLogic If you put a `console.log()` statement in as the first line in `OnTriggerStay()` and nothing happens when you would expect, then that function isn't running.  And then, you have completely narrowed down the problem as far as the code you pasted goes.  I don't know Unity, so I couldn't help you beyond that.

Comment: @Brad When i do that i get a series syntax errors (one saying i should keep the brackets in and the other saying i should remove them) I put the revised code in the question

Comment: @CrudeLogic What you have is definitely a syntax error.  Try this:  `function OnTriggerStay(other : Collider) { console.log(arguments); }`

Comment: @Brad Now I get 3 more syntax errors. "console", "argument" and "other" are all unknown identifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your code is Ok. I setup new project.And your code works fine.
Possible pitfalls:
1. You misspell either player tag either level name
2. You did not add level in build settings
3. One of colliders has to have rigidbody - [docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerStay.html)

P.S. Problem was with a setup: mix colliders 2d and 3d.

Comment: Just to be clear. Did you setup new project, use your code, everything works fine? Then bug in your setup. So if you have any suggestion how I could check your setup I'm ready to help

Comment: The code works fine. I could send you the project, if you want, so you can check it.

Comment: Okay, i've sent it you on google drive. It's called "Stackoverflow thingy.zip"